# Clicking a button inside an EXE with an automated script

Tags: button, click

We have an EXE file, which communicates with our cloud server located outside of our network, and downloads workflow updates and some database files on a daily basis. We don't have the source code for this application.

Whenever we restart our server, we need to manually start this application, and we need to click on the "start" button inside to make the application running.

We have added this application in the task scheduler, but the application pops up and waits for us to click the 'start' button. Is there any way to automate the clicking of the button inside this application using some script?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use some kind of script like vbscript to make this happen.

Comment: Do you feel comfortable writing native code? You can do this by getting a handle to the window using WinApi

Comment: I once had similar kind of problem which I solved by writing simple java app using robot class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this VB script

```
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.AppActivate yourAPP
    WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```